# Python TopicRank - NLP

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dataframe named 'maindf' which have these two columns[image]

Now I have code of TopicRank from Python (https://boudinfl.github.io/pke/build/html/unsupervised.html#topicrank) which gave me the output for the first row.

Output is like:

[image]

Now, I want to iterate over 149 rows and need to append it to a new column called 'keywords'.

As I'm new to NLP, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have defined a function and iterated using lambda for Topicrank algorithm.

[image]

which solved my problem.

this is the function that I have defined

[image]

after running this it iterated all the rows and added all the keywords to the new columns called keywords.